# Cassandra file structure - how are the files used?

Tags: nosql, cassandra

When experimenting with Cassandra I've observed that Cassandra writes to the following files:

```
/.../cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-<id>.log
/.../cassandra/data/Keyspace1/Standard1-1-Data.db
/.../cassandra/data/Keyspace1/Standard1-1-Filter.db
/.../cassandra/data/Keyspace1/Standard1-1-Index.db
/.../cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-1-Data.db
/.../cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-1-Filter.db
/.../cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-1-Index.db
/.../cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-2-Data.db
/.../cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-2-Filter.db
/.../cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-2-Index.db
/.../cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-3-Data.db
/.../cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-3-Filter.db
/.../cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-3-Index.db
/.../cassandra/system.log
```

The general structure seems to be:

```
/.../cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-ID.log
/.../cassandra/data/KEYSPACE/COLUMN_FAMILY-N-Data.db
/.../cassandra/data/KEYSPACE/COLUMN_FAMILY-N-Filter.db
/.../cassandra/data/KEYSPACE/COLUMN_FAMILY-N-Index.db
/.../cassandra/system.log
```

What is the Cassandra file structure? More specifically, how are the `data`, `commitlog` directories used, and what is the structure of the files in the `data` directory (`Data`/`Filter`/`Index`)?

Comment: Way to dive in and understand what's going on under the hood in Cassandra!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A write to a Cassandra node first hits the **CommitLog** (sequential). (Then Cassandra stores values to column-family specific, in-memory data structures called Memtables. The Memtables are flushed to disk whenever one of the configurable thresholds is exceeded. (1, datasize in memtable. 2, # of objects reach certain limit, 3, lifetime of a memtable expires.))

The **data** folder contains a subfolder for each keyspace. Each subfolder contains three kind of files:

- Data files: An SSTable (nomenclature
  borrowed from Google) stands for
  Sorted Strings Table and is a file of
  key-value string pairs (sorted by
  keys).
- Index file: (Key, offset) pairs (points into data file)
- [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter): all keys in data file

Comment: Thanks. The Cassandra wiki is a good place to start if you want to have a more in-depth understanding/description about terminology and nomenclature used in Cassandra

Answer (score 22):

[Cassandra File Format in detail](http://blog.csdn.net/firecoder/article/details/7019435)

Each ColumnFamily(Eg. object) in separated sstable files

```
ColumnFamilyName-version-#-Data.db
ColumnFamilyName-version-#-Index.db
ColumnFamilyName-version-#-Filter.db
```

[image]